# Azure AD B2C getting oauthConnection Error: Bad Request

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

While trying to integrate Azure AD B2C, I am stuck with an error "oauthConnection Error: Bad Request". Following their given sample [app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-ios-native-nxoauth2-b2c) it all works fine. But after integrating the same copy paste code from the working sample app, and trying to log in with **Facebook** or **Google Plus**, it throws an error! I am pretty sure that every credential that I used in the sample app is the same for my app. Any idea about this will be highly appreciated. Here is my code,  *AppDelegate.m*

```
#import "AppData.h"
#import "NXOAuth2.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    [self setupOAuth2AccountStore];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}

- (void)setupOAuth2AccountStore {
    AppData *data = [AppData getInstance]; // The singleton we use to get the settings

    NSDictionary *customHeaders =
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                                forKey:@"Content-Type"];

    // Azure B2C needs
    // kNXOAuth2AccountStoreConfigurationAdditionalAuthenticationParameters for
    // sending policy to the server,
    // therefore we use -setConfiguration:forAccountType:
    NSDictionary *B2cConfigDict = @{
                                    kNXOAuth2AccountStoreConfigurationClientID : data.clientID,
                                    kNXOAuth2AccountStoreConfigurationSecret : data.clientSecret,
                                    kNXOAuth2AccountStoreConfigurationScope :
                                        [NSSet setWithObjects:@"openid", data.clientID, nil],
                                    kNXOAuth2AccountStoreConfigurationAuthorizeURL :
                                        [NSURL URLWithString:data.authURL],
                                    kNXOAuth2AccountStoreConfigurationTokenURL :
                                        [NSURL URLWithString:data.tokenURL],
                                    kNXOAuth2AccountStoreConfigurationRedirectURL :
                                        [NSURL URLWithString:data.bhh],
                                    kNXOAuth2AccountStoreConfigurationCustomHeaderFields : customHeaders,
                                    //      kNXOAuth2AccountStoreConfigurationAdditionalAuthenticationParameters:customAuthenticationParameters
                                    };

    [[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] setConfiguration:B2cConfigDict
                                          forAccountType:data.accountIdentifier];
}
```

*LoginViewController.m*

```
#import "AppData.h"
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "NXOAuth2.h"

@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController {

    NSURL *myLoadedUrl;
    bool isRequestBusy;
}

// Put variables here

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // OAuth2 Code
    self.loginView.delegate = self;
    [self requestOAuth2Access];
    [self setupOAuth2AccountStore];
    NSURLCache *URLCache =
    [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:4 * 1024 * 1024
                                  diskCapacity:20 * 1024 * 1024
                                      diskPath:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];

}


- (void)resolveUsingUIWebView:(NSURL *)URL {
    // We get the auth token from a redirect so we need to handle that in the
    // webview.

    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(resolveUsingUIWebView:)
                               withObject:URL
                            waitUntilDone:YES];
        return;
    }

    NSURLRequest *hostnameURLRequest =
    [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL
                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                 timeoutInterval:10.0f];
    isRequestBusy = YES;
    [self.loginView loadRequest:hostnameURLRequest];

    NSLog(@"resolveUsingUIWebView ready (status: UNKNOWN, URL: %@)",
          self.loginView.request.URL);
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    AppData *data = [AppData getInstance];

    NSLog(@"webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest: %@ (%li)", request.URL,
          (long)navigationType);

    // The webview is where all the communication happens. Slightly complicated.

    myLoadedUrl = [webView.request mainDocumentURL];
    NSLog(@"***Loaded url: %@", myLoadedUrl);

    // if the UIWebView is showing our authorization URL or consent URL, show the
    // UIWebView control
    if ([request.URL.absoluteString rangeOfString:data.authURL
                                          options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]
        .location != NSNotFound) {
        self.loginView.hidden = NO;
    } else if ([request.URL.absoluteString rangeOfString:data.loginURL
                                                 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]
               .location != NSNotFound) {
        // otherwise hide the UIWebView, we've left the authorization flow
        self.loginView.hidden = NO;
    } else if ([request.URL.absoluteString rangeOfString:data.bhh
                                                 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]
               .location != NSNotFound) {
        // otherwise hide the UIWebView, we've left the authorization flow
        self.loginView.hidden = YES;
        [[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] handleRedirectURL:request.URL];
    } else {
        self.loginView.hidden = NO;

    }

    return YES;
}







#pragma mark - UIWebViewDelegate methods
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
  // The webview is where all the communication happens. Slightly complicated.
}
- (void)handleOAuth2AccessResult:(NSURL *)accessResult {
    // parse the response for success or failure
    if (accessResult)
        // if success, complete the OAuth2 flow by handling the redirect URL and
        // obtaining a token
    {
        [[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore] handleRedirectURL:accessResult];
    } else {
        // start over
        [self requestOAuth2Access];
    }
}
- (void)setupOAuth2AccountStore {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserverForName:NXOAuth2AccountStoreAccountsDidChangeNotification
     object:[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore]
     queue:nil
     usingBlock:^(NSNotification *aNotification) {
         if (aNotification.userInfo) {
             // account added, we have access
             // we can now request protected data
             NSLog(@"Success!! We have an access token.");
         } else {
             // account removed, we lost access
         }
     }];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserverForName:NXOAuth2AccountStoreDidFailToRequestAccessNotification
     object:[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore]
     queue:nil
     usingBlock:^(NSNotification *aNotification) {
         NSError *error = [aNotification.userInfo
                           objectForKey:NXOAuth2AccountStoreErrorKey];

        // Always got stuck here while trying to login with any credentials
         NSLog(@"Error!! %@", error.localizedDescription);
     }];
}


- (void)requestOAuth2Access {
    AppData *data = [AppData getInstance];

    [[NXOAuth2AccountStore sharedStore]
     requestAccessToAccountWithType:data.accountIdentifier
     withPreparedAuthorizationURLHandler:^(NSURL *preparedURL) {

         NSURLRequest *r = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:preparedURL];
         [self.loginView loadRequest:r];
     }];
}
```

*ViewController.m*

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppData.h"
#import "LoginViewController.h"
#import "NXOAuth2.h"
// Login Action
    - (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
        LoginViewController *userSelectController =
        [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:userSelectController
                                             animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the URL that is returned where the bad request occurs? It sounds like the URL or the request is potentially not formed correctly.

Comment: https://login.microsoftonline.com/swayamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_B2c_Mallik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case if anybody stumbles in this, Here is the solution

Go to pod, NXOAuth2Client.m and replace the method 
`- (void)requestTokenWithAuthGrant:(NSString *)authGrant redirectURL:(NSURL *)redirectURL;` with the below code

```
- (void)requestTokenWithAuthGrant:(NSString *)authGrant redirectURL:(NSURL *)redirectURL;
{
    NSAssert1(!authConnection, @"authConnection already running with: %@", authConnection);

    NSMutableURLRequest *tokenRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:tokenURL];
    [tokenRequest setHTTPMethod:self.tokenRequestHTTPMethod];
    [authConnection cancel];  // just to be sure

    self.authenticating = YES;

    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                       @"authorization_code", @"grant_type",
                                       clientId, @"client_id",
                                      // clientSecret, @"client_secret",
                                       [redirectURL absoluteString], @"redirect_uri",
                                       authGrant, @"code",
                                       nil];
    if (self.desiredScope) {
        [parameters setObject:[[self.desiredScope allObjects] componentsJoinedByString:@" "] forKey:@"scope"];
    }

    if (self.customHeaderFields) {
        [self.customHeaderFields enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSString *obj, BOOL *stop) {
            [tokenRequest addValue:obj forHTTPHeaderField:key];
        }];
    }

    if (self.additionalAuthenticationParameters) {
        [parameters addEntriesFromDictionary:self.additionalAuthenticationParameters];
    }

    authConnection = [[NXOAuth2Connection alloc] initWithRequest:tokenRequest
                                               requestParameters:parameters
                                                     oauthClient:self
                                                        delegate:self];
    authConnection.context = NXOAuth2ClientConnectionContextTokenRequest;
}
```

Commenting *clientSecret* solved the issue